# git deploying project - stashing warnings

Tags: git, deployment, push

I'm using `git` to deploy my site, however, I'm trying to figure out why using the following [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git/327315#327315), files keep accumulating in my list of `working copy`. Meaning that, every different file that I commit and push to my bare repository gets listed as: `M filename.php`

Also, I'm wondering what does the following warnings mean? and how can I avoid them?

```
To mike@server10:/home/www/site1/.git
   07155f1..e80c2db  master -> master
Push to checked out branch refs/heads/master

W:unstaged changes found in working copy
W:stashing dirty working copy - see git-stash(1)

Saved working directory and index state "On (no branch): dirty working copy before update to e80c2db3212a7eb33da2e218001122e0decae640"

Checking out files: 100% (6362/6362), done.
HEAD is now at 07155f1 updated file path
trapped 22921
Updating working copy
M       image.php
M       ask.php
M       basic.php
HEAD is now at e80c2db updated text style
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your destination repo, which isn't bare (i.e. there is a `.git` plus a working copy checked out), isn't "clean": the "`git status`" would not return on that remote repo a clean status, like "`nothing to commit (working directory clean)`".

That is why you see stashing warning (Git tries to save the files "being modified").

You need first to make sure the remote repo has a clean status (by resetting its working tree to the latest commit on the deployment branch, making sure a `git branch` indicates that your are on that branch) before running this script.

Comment: Following from VonC's comment - perhaps you need to make the repo bare so that it stays clean, rather than having working stuff on that repo - do you/others actually do work on the repo....

Comment: @Philip Oakley: Yeah, actually that's what I was thinking. I've seen several ways that a deployment can be done using git, however, I'm still trying to find out perhaps an optimal way. Any ideas?

Comment: @Philip Oakley: No, I'm the only one working on that repository.

Comment: @Mike: alternatives are based on a bare repo and a post-update hook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753520/git-push-to-refs-remotes-mine-master/3753712#3753712 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062657/can-i-use-git-to-keep-a-remote-server-up-to-date/2062719#2062719

Answer (score 0):

Why not you just make the `hooks/post-receive` script do a `git checkout -f` to have it do a checkout from a bare repository into the deployment path?

Take a look on [how I did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13165630/412426).