# Deploying site with Git: post-update hook works first time, then never again

Tags: git, deployment, mediatemple

Having a strange issue with a git post-update hook. I created repository on my server (`/var/www/vhosts/git/master.git`) and in this repository added a post-update hook with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1
echo "*UPDATE*"

case " $1 " in
*'refs/heads/master'*)
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/vhosts/website.com/sandbox.website.com git checkout -f
    echo
    echo "Master was updated!"
    echo
    ;;
esac

case " $1 " in
*'refs/heads/sandbox'*)
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/vhosts/website.com/sandbox.website.com git checkout -f
    echo
    echo "Sandbox was updated!"
    echo
    ;;
esac
```

I made sure this file is executable. Then I created a local repository on my machine using:

```
$ mkdir website && cd website
$ git init
$ echo 'Testing.' > index.html
$ git add index.html
$ git commit -q -m "Initial commit"
$ git remote add web ssh://username@website.com/var/www/vhosts/website.com/git/master.git
$ git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

For whatever reason that first push works just fine—`/var/www/vhosts/website.com/sandbox.website.com` gets updated with the index file—but then none of the following pushes work. I get the response back from the `post-update` hook that says "Master was updated!" but the directory doesn't actually get updated.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have have a permission issue. Take a look on the permissions on the`/var/www/*` path and ensure that your git user has permission to read/write/delete on the files.

I have used a much [simpler technique](http://www.deanoj.co.uk/programming/git/using-git-and-a-post-receive-hook-script-for-auto-deployment/) (here is a detailed [script](http://caiustheory.com/automatically-deploying-website-from-remote-git-repository)) that allowed me to use my server as git server with gitolite and deploy on push without having to clone the repository on the `/var/www/myproject` path. It is working for me on `git 1.7.9` and `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS` with `Apache/2.2.22`.

1. Create your rpository on the server:

   ```
   mkdir myproject.git && cd myproject.git
   git init --bare
   ```
2. Configure the repository:

   ```
   git config core.worktree /var/www/myproject
   git config core.bare false
   git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
   ```
3. Edit or create the `hooks/post-receive` and make it runnable

   ```
   touch hooks/post-receive
   chmod u+x hooks/post-receive
   ```

Here is the file content:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
git checkout -f
```

You are ready to do a push and have it working.

My git user is called `git` and my apache used the `ubuntu` user. I had to edit the apache configuration on `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security` (you can do it on `/etc/apache2/http.conf` also) to include:

```
User git
Group git
```

Now my `/var/www/myproject` deploys all the files on push, creating the files with `git:git` user/group and my apache uses the same user/group to run.

Now you just have to restart your server or do a `service apache2 restart`