# How can I deploy my websites using Git hooks?

Tags: git, repository, githooks

I recently have started using Git in my daily workflow and I really love working with it.

I have a bare online repo (git init --bare --shared) sitting on my VPS under a folder called website.git and push pull changes to it from local whenever I need to, which works absolutely fine. Now, when I save data on my local repo, I push the changes online, but then I have to manually move the files into the public_html folder too, which as you can imagine, is a real pain.

I have tried using git hooks as described in http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto, but it's the permissions that are not working for me.

Both the public_html and website.git folders are owned by www-data:developers, but when the post-receive hook kicks in, it can't unlink the old files, and any new files are automatically owned by jack:jack which is the user I SSH into the server with.

My hooks/post-receive file is executable and contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/web/website.com/public_html git checkout -f
```

And my online repo is stored in

```
/home/web/website.com/website.git
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic operating-system permissions problem: when you use `ssh` to push changes, git uses `ssh` to connect to the remote host (as some user of your choosing—this is why the url allows ssh://*user@host*/path) so as to run the commands on the host that pick up the objects (commits, trees, blobs, and/or tags) being pushed and insert them into the target repo.  Whoever that user is, is then also running the hooks.  So when the post-receive hook runs, it's run as that user.

You could make the public_html directory more write-able (so that all your `git push` users can write to it); you could ssh in as user `www-data`; or you could use a set-uid program to make the `git checkout -f` run as the www-data user, with all the usual dangers of any set-uid program.  (The `sudo` command can be used for that last technique.  You'll want `sudo -n -u www-data` in the hook, I think, although I have never actually set this sort of thing up.)

---

Note: I experimented a bit and had an old (1.7.0.3) version of git on the target host.  This has a bug where relative paths fail.  To work around it, here is what I ended up with in `hooks/post-receive` (note, this is quite primitive as it does not check what was pushed-to):

```
#! /bin/sh
umask 0 # let everyone have write permission on everything
export GIT_DIR=$(readlink -f $(git rev-parse --git-dir))
export GIT_WORK_TREE=$(readlink -f /tmp/t)
(cd $GIT_WORK_TREE && git checkout -f)
```

In a newer git (with the bugs fixed) you won't need all of the above (although it does make the hook work when run manually, which is convenient).

Comment: Thanks for the info. You're right, it is a permissions issue! I set the public_html folder to 777, that way all users can write to it, modified a file, and then performed a push. No errors were present, and the files in public_html changed owners from www-data to jack (which as you say would since jack is running the hook), the files changed to 755 too, and when I opened one of the changed files, it still hadn't updated! I wonder how other people get this to work...?

Comment: Hm.  If you're willing to have everything be very write-able, try adding `umask 0` before doing `git checkout -f`.  Also, due to a bug fixed in git 1.7.4 I had to make sure that all paths were always absolute and that I did a "cd" to $GIT_WORK_TREE; see edit to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a permission issue similar to your and used [another technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13165630/412426) to do the deployment, but I did change my apache to use my git user. It is working for me on `git 1.7.9` and `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS` with `Apache/2.2.22`.

My git user is called `git` and my apache used the `ubuntu` user. I had to edit the apache configuration on `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security` (you can do it on `/etc/apache2/http.conf` also) to include:

```
User git
Group git
```

Now my `/var/www/myproject` deploys all the files on push, creating the files with `git:git` user/group and my apache uses the same user/group to run.

You can always add this to the end of yur `hooks/post-receive` script:

```
chown -R www-data:developers /home/web/website.com/public_html
```

Now you just have to restart your server or do a `service apache2 restart`